# What are shunts, as related to their use in current sensing in microcontrollers?

Tags: microcontroller, resistors, sensor, shunt, current-sensing

Within the manual for the I/O module I'm using (a Loytec LIOB-153) there are wiring diagrams to aid in wiring up your sensors and other inputs/outputs. There are two wiring diagrams for the purpose of showing you how to wire up 4-20mA transmitters as an input. The first wiring diagram describes the input as having an internal shunt. The second wiring diagram tells you that there are other inputs where you must supply your own 249 ohm shunt. What is the purpose of these resistor shunts?

[image: internal shunt]

[image: external shunt]

Comment: V = I * R.  I = V/R.  R is known, measure V you get i.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of the shunt is to convert the current through the loop to a voltage (by using a known resistance). The voltage can then be measured using an analog to digital converter and the current through the loop can be calculated.

Comment: I think it's making a little more sense. So the voltage drop over the resistor is what's measured?

Comment: The beauty of this system is that only 2 wires are needed and it has reasonably good noise immunity over long distances.

Comment: Yes - When there is 4 mA in the loop, the shunt resistor will have a voltage of 0.996 volts (.004 A * 249 ohms) across it. When there is 20 mA in the loop the shunt resistor will have a voltage of 4.98 volts (.020 A * 249 ohms) across it.